# Regarding STM32 interrupts -The Interrupt triggering for Switch-2, when the Switch-2 is in idle while operating with Switch-1:

Tags: stm32

I am using STM32L072CZ  microcontroller for my development purpose.
I am integrating STM32L072CZ with LoRa communication for our project. I wrote the application layer on the base firmware of LoRa LSN50-V2(node with integrated STM32 and Lora chip)
In that I configure the 2 interrupt pins in both rising and falling edge.
I configure the pin In such way which i mentioned below, and also i am using macros for the pins, pin's clock and pin's port

pin Initialization and Configuration and Deinitialization

```
void  mainInit( void  )
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct={0};
    GPIO_MAIN_CLK_ENABLE();
  
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin  = GPIO_MAIN_PIN; 
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode =GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;   
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed=GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;

  HW_GPIO_Init( GPIO_MAIN_PORT, GPIO_MAIN_PIN, &GPIO_InitStruct );
    
    /* Enable and set EXTI lines 4 to 15 Interrupt to the lowest priority */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_15_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_15_IRQn);
}

void  dgInit( void  )
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct={0};
    GPIO_DG_CLK_ENABLE();
    
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin  = GPIO_DG_PIN;   
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode =GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;   
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed=GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;

  HW_GPIO_Init( GPIO_DG_PORT, GPIO_DG_PIN, &GPIO_InitStruct );
    
    /* Enable and set EXTI lines 4 to 15 Interrupt to the lowest priority */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_15_IRQn, 1, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_15_IRQn);
}
void  mainIoDeInit( void  )
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct={0};
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode =GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;
  HW_GPIO_Init( GPIO_MAIN_PORT, GPIO_MAIN_PIN, &GPIO_InitStruct );
}

void  dgIoDeInit( void  )
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct={0};   
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode =GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;    
  HW_GPIO_Init( GPIO_DG_PORT, GPIO_DG_PIN, &GPIO_InitStruct );
}

/* IRQ handler functionality*/

 //HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler( GPIO_PIN_14 );

            if (joined_flags==1)
    {   
            
      if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_DG_PIN)!=RESET)    
        {
         HAL_Delay(30);
         mainStreamer=0;
         dgStreamer=1;
         __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_DG_PIN);
         HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_DG_PIN);  
                
        }
        
   
  //HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler( GPIO_PIN_15 );

        if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_MAIN_PIN)!=RESET)
        {   
         
         HAL_Delay(30);
         mainStreamer=1;
         dgStreamer=0;
         __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_MAIN_PIN);
         HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_MAIN_PIN);
            
                
        }
    }
```

I used PB14 and PB15 as a interrupt pin.

PB14-Switch-1
PB15-Switch-2

Most of the times the interrupt with proper switch status is updated. But sometimes there was a issue.

The issue is when the Switch-2 is in idle state, i am controlling the Switch 1 alone, in that sometimes i observed that the Switch-2 interrupt ISR happens instead of Switch 1 ISR.

what is the reason for that?

Comment: There is only one interrupt shared by these two pins.  When you get that single interrupt you have to read the status registers to determine what happened.  What makes you think  "the switch 2 ISR happens"?

Comment: I am setting the flags in the each IRQ handler, According to the flag , the condition is written to read the pin status and and send via LoRa to the Network Server. In that i am observing this kind of issue.

Comment: What do you mean "each IRQ"?  There is only one IRQ.

Comment: Yes!!! But what i meant is IRQ handler's each pins!

Comment: In the above mentioned code, I am fixing mainStreamer=0, and dg streamer =1 one pin , and vice versa for the other pin. Based on the flag, I did one function by reading the Interrupt pin status. That function i mentioned below. By that print statement I am verfying this issue.

Comment: void mainDgInterrupt(void)
{
    if(Main_Flag==1 && DG_Flag==0 )
    {    
           Main_Supply_status=HAL_GPIO_ReadPin( MAIN_PORT, MAIN_PIN);  
           AT_PRINTF("The Main Supply status is: %d\n\r",Main_Supply_status);     
       MAIN_DG_Send();
    }
   else if(Main_Flag==0 && DG_Flag==1 )
    { 

          DG_Supply_status = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(DG_PORT,DG_PIN); 
          AT_PRINTF("The DG Supply Status %d \n\r",DG_Supply_status);     
     MAIN_DG_Send();
     
    }


}